# How to get Medium Blog post in AMP html website?

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-amp

I am working on [AMP project](https://www.ampproject.org/). I want my blog posts on AMP website.

How can i get all blog post in AMP Website. [Medium](https://medium.com/) Give me RSS feed for my blog in json format. So my problem is that how i can get POST from medium.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get your Medium stories on your AMP site, you'll need to make a call to the RSS. If you can make the call on the back end, and render the response through your chosen HTML templating language, you can get your blog posts into the site and not break validation.

Doing it on the front end is difficult, because AMP forbids all user-written javascript. You can maybe look into `<amp-form>` AMP component to see if you can adapt it for your needs.